# Android OpenCv.mk file does not exist

Tags: android, opencv

I am getting following error:

```
jni/Android.mk:8: ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk: No such file or directory
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk'.  Stop.
```

I looked under Android.mk file it refers to OpenCv.mk file which is not found. Under my OpenCv folder i dont have any sdk folder and nor can i find OpenCv.mk file. Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry guys i think i downloaded wrong version. I downloaded OpenCV for windows should have downloaded OpenCV for android. May be this can help someone in future i used wrong link. Here is right link to the site:
http://opencv.org/downloads.html

Their you can download OpenCV fo android.